# reshape() function to make data long to wide in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

```
set.seed(2023)

ID<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
State<-c("NY","NY","NC","NC","TX","TX","VA","VA","SC","SC")
Gender<-c("Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife")
stress<-rnorm(10,0,1)
satisfaction<-rnorm(10,0,1)

data<-data.frame(ID,State,Gender,stress,satisfaction)
```

This is a reproducible minimal example.
I want to make a dataset as below
by using reshape() function

```
ID<-1:5
State<-c("NY","NC","TX","VA","SC")
Husband_stress<-rnorm(5,0,1)
Wife_stress<-rnorm(5,0,1)
Husband_satisfaction<-rnorm(5,0,1)
Wife_satisfaction<-rnorm(5,0,1)

results<-data.frame(ID,State,Husband_stress,Wife_stress,Husband_satisfaction,Wife_satisfaction)
```

However, I only can use standard evaluation
which means that I cannot use tidyverse or other pacakge.

Comment: I'm curious if you could explain the context/motivation for "I only can use standard evaluation" -- "non-standard evaluation" is a feature of many base R functions. Do you mean this is an assignment where you can't use any non-base packages?

Comment: Have you looked at the help for `?reshape` or any online tutorials, and tried something?

Comment: @Jon Spring Yes I tried and I failed. this is not my assignment I am not a student. because Tidyverse evaluation can be unstable, and I want to learn this function and then apply that knowledge to my new package (that my colleague will use.) You don't have to be hostile to the less experienced in R. I am stuck at this phase and need help so I made a new reproducible data to get help.

Comment: How to reshape data from long to wide format <- this question does not apply to my question it is different. I need to combine two (husband/ column name) while those example is just simply re shaping.

Comment: I would use `data |> tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Gender,  values_from = c(stress, satisfaction), names_glue = "{Gender}_{.value}")` to create your desired output but it sounds like you would prefer a solution using something else.

Comment: One could adopt the first answer from the duplicated question: `reshape(data, idvar = c("ID", "State"), timevar = "Gender", direction = "wide")` to get something close, though I am unfamiliar how to make the column names match your desired ones.

Comment: I apologize that my first comment came across hostile, that was certainly not my intention. I have often found it helpful to get context for a question's requirements when they are unfamiliar to me; that can help me learn about things I haven't considered before, and sometimes uncover misunderstandings in the premise of a question that might yield a better approach. In my 2nd comment, I should have requested more explicitly that those efforts where you looked for help or tried something should be included in your question. That helps us understand where you are running into trouble.