# duplicated_ reshape() function in R long to wide

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Duplicated from this [reshape() function to make data long to wide in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77184128/reshape-function-to-make-data-long-to-wide-in-r)

This was closed but I don't get it

Because [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)
this is just simple reshaping but
my question is not simply reshaping.

If it is simply reshaping, I can do it,
but I need to combine columns to make it wide
(e.g., husband + stress)

This is not my assignment, ( I am not a student)
and I am trying to learn to reshape, and I am stuck in this stage.

```
set.seed(2023)

ID<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
State<-c("NY","NY","NC","NC","TX","TX","VA","VA","SC","SC")
Gender<-c("Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife","Husband","Wife")
stress<-rnorm(10,0,1)
satisfaction<-rnorm(10,0,1)

data<-data.frame(ID,State,Gender,stress,satisfaction)
```

This is a reproducible minimal example.
I want to make a dataset as below
by using reshape() function

```
ID<-1:5
State<-c("NY","NC","TX","VA","SC")
Husband_stress<-rnorm(5,0,1)
Wife_stress<-rnorm(5,0,1)
Husband_satisfaction<-rnorm(5,0,1)
Wife_satisfaction<-rnorm(5,0,1)

results<-data.frame(ID,State,Husband_stress,Wife_stress,Husband_satisfaction,Wife_satisfaction)
```

However, I only can use standard evaluation
which means that I cannot use tidyverse or other pacakge.
(because it is unstable to be in package)

Comment: Please see my two suggested solutions in the comments to your first question. This certainly looks like a reshaping to wide question, so I would encourage you to try those two solutions to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` you can either do it directly with `dcast` but this names the columns differently than in your preferred outcome, or you first `melt` it to *long* and then `dcast` it to *wide* again.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

dcast(data, ID + State ~ Gender, value.var = c("satisfaction", "stress"))

#    ID State satisfaction_Husband satisfaction_Wife stress_Husband stress_Wife
# 1:  1    NY              0.32696          -0.41275      -0.083784    -0.98294
# 2:  2    NC              0.56204           0.66336      -1.875067    -0.18614
# 3:  3    TX             -0.60290           0.69838      -0.633486     1.09080
# 4:  4    VA              0.59585           0.45209      -0.913727     1.00164
# 5:  5    SC              0.89674           0.57222      -0.399267    -0.46812

dcast(
  melt(data, id.vars = c("ID", "State", "Gender")),
  ID + State ~ Gender + variable
)

#    ID State Husband_stress Husband_satisfaction Wife_stress Wife_satisfaction
# 1:  1    NY      -0.083784              0.32696    -0.98294          -0.41275
# 2:  2    NC      -1.875067              0.56204    -0.18614           0.66336
# 3:  3    TX      -0.633486             -0.60290     1.09080           0.69838
# 4:  4    VA      -0.913727              0.59585     1.00164           0.45209
# 5:  5    SC      -0.399267              0.89674    -0.46812           0.57222
```